# Return variables from Flask to template without rendering the template

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask, return

I'm building a Flask app and I've come to the point where I'm rendering a template to display some data on a table. In this template I have a button which takes me to a view function that makes some statistical analysis on the data. After this analysis, I want to display the statistics on the same template without re-rendering it. In short terms, I want to press the button and the data to be displayed right there without reloading the page. So far, I don't know how to do that as I always return "render_template" or "redirect" from my view functions.

I was thinking if there is a way to return the data from the view function into a javascript script into the template and then this script to handle how to display them but I can't figure out how.

Edit for duplicate:

I tried the solutions suggested on the duplicate question. Specifically, I have now as a return:

```
return json.dumps(avg)
```

or

```
return jsonify(avg)
```

but now it just displays a blank page with my list (avg). What I want is  not to reload the page but to display the data within the template in which I clicked the button.

Comment: Look into [AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: That did the trick, I can now get the data to javascript. All  I want to do now is to find a way to display them in my html, thank you.